# Glassfish Illegal character in path at index 8: My Program.war

Tags: java, glassfish

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index
>   8: My Program.war     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:859)    at
>   java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1043)   at
>   org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.getOutputFileURI(PayloadFilesManager.java:413)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.extractFile(PayloadFilesManager.java:502)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.access$600(PayloadFilesManager.java:93)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager$DataRequestType$1.processPart(PayloadFilesManager.java:753)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.processPartsExtended(PayloadFilesManager.java:622)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$UploadedFilesManager.extractFiles(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1990)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$UploadedFilesManager.(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1962)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$UploadedFilesManager.(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1941)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1119)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 8:
>   My Program.war    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3086)  at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3044)  at
>   java.net.URI.(URI.java:595)     at
>   java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)     ... 34 more

I know that the issue is there is a space in "My Program.war", I just don't know how to get rid of it. Originally, my Java project was called "My Program", but since I've been getting this error I renamed it to "My-Program". This has changed the folder name and project name, but for some reason when I deploy my Glassfish application, it tries to use the old name. How can I update this information?

Comment: show us your code at PayloadFilesManager.java:413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space in the file name will be caused by misconfiguration of your IDE.

A workaround would be to:

1. Build, rather than deploy, your project which will create a WAR file called `My Program.war`. The output log in your IDE should tell you the location where it is built
2. Rename the file to `MyProgram.war`
3. Deploy the file to GlassFish manually. There are [instructions in this blog post](http://blog.payara.fish/how-to-deploy-an-application-on-payara-server-or-glassfish). The easiest way is probably just to copy it to the autodeploy folder: `glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy`

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `asadmin undeploy <appname>` (without the .war extension), but that is also assuming that it was deployed. I am not sure that it was in your case but you can check with `asadmin list-applications`.